# jTable - how to show only show limited columns? Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jdeveloper

This is the code for the "creation" of the table I have in my DataAccessLayer.

```
private TableModel getResultSetAsDefaultTableModel(ResultSet rs) {

    try {

        String[] columnHeadings = new String[0];
        Object[][] dataArray = new Object[0][0];

        ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = md.getColumnCount();

        for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
            String columnName = md.getColumnName(i);
            columnHeadings = Arrays.copyOf(columnHeadings, columnHeadings.length + 1);
            columnHeadings[i - 1] = columnName;
        }

        int r = 0;

        while (rs.next()) {

            Object[] row = new Object[columnCount];
            for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
                row[i - 1] = rs.getObject(i);
            }

            dataArray = Arrays.copyOf(dataArray, dataArray.length + 1);
            dataArray[r] = row;

            r++;
        }

        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(dataArray, columnHeadings) {
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {

                return false;
            }
        };

        return dtm;

    } catch (SQLException ex) {

        Logger.getLogger(Dataaccesslayer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return null;

}
```

**This results in some complications, since one of my tables has 50 different columns and therefore you can't read the columnnames or what is in the cell.

The problem is that the table's values are determined by the metadata...

I want to limit the columns that are showed to a specific number (5) for all tables. 
How do I do it?**

Kind regards,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

you can remove tables if you want to...

```
int amountColumns = table.getColumnModel().getColumnCount(); //count columns
TableColumn c6 = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(6); //identif a random column
table.getColumnModel().removeColumn(c6); //remove this column
```

i hope that helped...

Answer (score 0):

I would not remove them but change their size to 0.

```
int amountColumns = table.getColumnModel().getColumnCount(); //count columns
TableColumn c6 = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(6); //identif a random column
table.getColumnModel().setMin(0);
table.getColumnModel().setMax(0);
table.getColumnModel().setPreferredWidth(0);
```

Like i answered you in your other thread...

Comment: there is another thread?! ouh, then lets close this! can you set onhold? (i think i cant yet, or, can i?)

Comment: yes here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655197/jtable-in-gui-java-does-not-show-all-data-from-database-error-in-tablemodel. I can't set to onhold: Users with 3000 reputation can cast up to 50 close votes per day. When a question reaches 5 close votes, it is marked [on hold], and will no longer accept answers.

Comment: rtfm, haha, right, i found it by myself then now ^^ what a pity, duplicates should be marked more easily