# jTable in GUI (java) does not show all data from database! error in TableModel?

Tags: java, sql, user-interface, jtable

This is a last resort. I'm studying development of Information Systems and even my teachers can't solve this... this is a nut for you to crack!!

This is the problem: My jTable in GUI gives me this:

[image]

This is what Microsoft Management Studio shows me:

[image]

**As you can tell the jTable (GUI) has got 2 main problems:**

1. The columnname "Name" does not contain any information. And it should? Why isn't it showing?
2. Since as you can tell, the table contains several columns, too many to even show. I therefore want to "add a restriction" that changes so that the jTable only shows the first 6 columns.

**This is the code for the "creation of the table", in the DataAccessLayer:**

```
    private TableModel getResultSetAsDefaultTableModel(ResultSet rs) {
    try {

        String[] columnHeadings = new String[0];
        Object[][] dataArray = new Object[0][0];


        ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = md.getColumnCount();

        for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
            String columnName = md.getColumnName(i);
            columnHeadings = Arrays.copyOf(columnHeadings, columnHeadings.length + 1);
            columnHeadings[i - 1] = columnName;
            }

        int r = 0;

        while (rs.next()) {

            Object[] row = new Object[columnCount];
            for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
                row[i - 1] = rs.getObject(i);
            }

            dataArray = Arrays.copyOf(dataArray, dataArray.length + 1);
            dataArray[r] = row;

            r++;
        }

        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(dataArray, columnHeadings) {
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {

                return false;
            }
        };

        return dtm;

    } catch (SQLException ex) {

        Logger.getLogger(Dataaccesslayer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return null;

}
```

**If you want me to show you the path of the code (frame, controller) just say so and I'll post it.**

I would be so thankful if anyone can solve this...

Regards,

Christian

Comment: Use a debugger to check if the value is retrieved properly from the database (or add a `System.out.println(row[i - 1])` inside the loop over the columns. It might not be the code that reads the data, but the code that displays it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because in your for loop it should say `i = 0;` and not `i = 1;` since the first information (the name) is at index 0 right ?

In your case it could be enough to just leave the for-loop as it is and change this line `to:row[i - 1] = rs.getObject(i-1);`

To hide or show columns you could call `setMin` `setMax` and `setPreferredWidth` on your TableColumn.

Comment: In which for loop do you mean? The one in the while loop?

Comment: yes, but i think for loops from 0 to <count are much more readable. You should think of changing them in future projects

Comment: It doesnt work. The problem is that it isnt always the first column that doesnt show, sometimes its the third. But its always the column 'name'.

Comment: just try to log what data comes via `rs.next()` and also log at which index you try to save the data in your array. Then have a look at your array if all the data is in the place you expect it to be

Comment: "*since the first information is at index 0 right*" - No. The column index starts at `1` for `ResultSet.getXXX()` methods

Comment: So @a_horse_with_no_name whats the problem then? Why doesnt tables show the names? Everything else shows in the other columns

Answer (score 0):

Change your method like next, I think it helps you:

```
private TableModel getResultSetAsDefaultTableModel(ResultSet rs) {
    try {

        List<String> columnHeadings = new ArrayList<String>();
        Object[][] dataArray = new Object[0][0];

        ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = md.getColumnCount();

        for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
            columnHeadings.add(md.getColumnName(i));
        }

        int r = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            Object[] row = new Object[columnCount];
            for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
                row[i-1] = rs.getObject(i);
            }
            dataArray = Arrays.copyOf(dataArray, dataArray.length + 1);
            dataArray[r] = row;
            r++;
        }

        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(dataArray,columnHeadings.toArray(new Object[columnHeadings.size()])) {
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }
        };

        return dtm;

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Dataaccesslayer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

For showing not all columns use `dtm.setColumnCount(2);`. Here 2 is column count to show.